# Sort a csv file by first column timestamp

Tags: php, arrays, csv, sorting, timestamp

I have a csv file like this

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
Thdj,jj,jjj,gg
```

Assuming that a, d and Thdj are timestamp, how can i sort those rows by descending order (from the nearest timestamp to the farther in the future), deleting past timestamps?

I have to print an output like this
table

---

10/12/2017 | bar  | foo

---

22/12/2017 |spam| eggs

I am stuck there

```
<?php
$i=array();
$e=array_map('str_getcsv', file('0.csv'));
foreach ($e as $o){
array_push($i,$o[0]);
}
echo var_dump($i);
?>
```

and the result i get is

array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "d" [2]=> string(4) "Thdj" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (tested in php 5.6):

```
<?php

// timestamps before this date will be ignored
$filter_date = new DateTime();

// stores all rows with timestamp after filter_date
$rows = [];

// read csv
$file = fopen('test.csv', 'rb');
while ($row = fgetcsv($file)) {
    $row_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $row[0]);
    if ($row_date >= $filter_date) {
        // add date to row for ordering function
        array_unshift($row, $row_date);
        // store row
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
}
fclose($file);

// sort rows by datetime objects
usort($rows, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a[0] < $b[0]) {
        return -1;
    }
    if ($a[0] > $b[0]) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});

// output rows
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // remove datetime object from each row before printing
    array_shift($row);
    echo implode(' | ', $row) . "\n";
}
```

With this csv file:

```
08/12/2017,bar,foo
22/12/2017,spam,eggs
10/12/2017,bar,foo
```

Gives this output:

```
10/12/2017 | bar | foo
22/12/2017 | spam | eggs
```

And if you mean that your CSV file contains unix timestamps instead of d/m/Y, you can change the `DateTime::createFromFormat` line to `DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $row[0])` to read the timestamps, and then use the datetime object's `format` method to output the timestamp in whatever format you like.

Comment: Sorry, but i have PHP 5.6 installed on my server

Comment: What should i use instead of  "<=>" (spaceship operator) ?

Comment: I've updated my answer for php 5.6, removing the `<=>` operator